# nohup ssh on osx

Tags: ssh, osx, nohup

The following two commands (aligned to highlight syntactical changes), which differ only in the means by which commands are delivered to the shell, work fine on receivers running a variety of linux-based operating systems (debian, centos, opensuse, etc.):

```
$ ssh u@h "nohup bash -c 'echo testing' -- >/path/out 2>/path/err &"
$ echo                   'echo testing' \
| ssh u@h "nohup bash -s                -- >/path/out 2>/path/err &"
```

For no apparent reason, the second one (using `bash -s`) fails when the receiving node (`h`) is running OS X (10.9.5): the files for the redirected streams are created but nothing is written to `stdout`. If the command is not forked to the background, then the `bash -s` syntax works on an OS X receiver:

```
$ echo                   'echo testing' \
| ssh u@h "nohup bash -s                -- >/path/out 2>/path/err"
```

Because of the inconsistent behavior, I cannot tell whether the problem stems from the `nohup` on mac or the behavior of `bash -s` or the interaction between the two; I don't see any hanging processes on the receiving end; the job sent by `ssh` appears to simply vanish after the `ssh` session disconnects. `disown`ing the job does not help either. The version of `bash` on the receiving OS X system is `GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`. The receiving linux systems, on which all the `nohup`/`ssh` commands work, are using various versions of `bash` 4 (4.2+).

Can this be fixed by changing the configuration of the receiver's `ssh`?

Comment: Can you provide the mac's bash version? can you try a different installation of bash, e.g. from homebrew?

Comment: @Abdul: `which bash` --version : GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13). I edited the question as well. I'll try using a version of `bash` from `homebrew`; thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Abdul: I upgraded to `bash v4.4.12(1)` on the OS X system and modified `/etc/shells` and `$PATH` accordingly. Unfortunately, it did not help.